# Many internal std library compile errors when trying to compile on MSYS2/MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm trying to statically link and compile my project on MSYS2/MingGW-w64 on Windows 10. However the internal std library spits out a ton of compile errors, and I mean a LOT, over 2k lines and 200 KB. How can I fix this?

Here's the first error block:

```
/mingw64/bin/g++.exe   -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/build -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/block -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/cliParser -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/mapArt/mapArtFlat -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/mapArt/mapArtStaircase -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/palette -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/schematic -I/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/staircaseColumn -I/mingw64/include/GraphicsMagick -I/home/dan9e/libnbtplusplus/include -I/home/dan9e/libnbtplusplus/include/libnbtplusplus -I/home/dan9e/libnbtplusplus/include/libnbtplusplus/io -I/home/dan9e/libnbtplusplus/include/libnbtplusplus/text -I/mingw64/include/tclap -I/mingw64/include/spdlog -I/mingw64/include/fmt  -g -O2 -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cartogrtist.dir/src/block/block.cpp.obj -c /home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/block/block.cpp
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/string:56,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/locale:39,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/fmt/locale.h:11,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/clocale:42,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/c++locale.h:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/localefwd.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from C:/msys64/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/block/block.h:19,
                 from C:/msys64/home/dan9e/cartogrtist/src/block/block.cpp:17:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc: In function 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:1484:15: error: 'ctype' does not name a type; did you mean '_wctype'?
 1484 |       typedef ctype<_CharT>    __ctype_type;
      |               ^~~~~
      |               _wctype
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:1485:24: error: '__ctype_type' has not been declared
 1485 |       typedef typename __ctype_type::ctype_base         __ctype_base;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:1501:14: error: '__ctype_type' does not name a type; did you mean '__ctype_base'?
 1501 |        const __ctype_type& __ct = use_facet<__ctype_type>(___in.getloc());
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              __ctype_base
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:1507:12: error: '__ct' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '__c'?
 1507 |        && !__ct.is(__ctype_base::space,
      |            ^~~~
      |            __c
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:1507:20: error: '__ctype_base' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
 1507 |        && !__ct.is(__ctype_base::space,
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The rest can be found at: https://pastebin.com/RaiS6K75

The make command is:

```sh
dan9e@RED MINGW64 ~/cartogrtist/build
$ make -j1 1> error.log 2> error.log
```

`CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` was set to `ON` in CMake in order to show the commands being run.

Version info:

```sh
dan9e@RED MINGW64 ~/cartogrtist/build
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


dan9e@RED MINGW64 ~/cartogrtist/build
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.17.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

dan9e@RED MINGW64 ~/cartogrtist/build
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-msys
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the first few errors as text.

Comment: `locale.h` several files have the same name, and the wrong one gets picked up.

Comment: Try and include a Minimal, Reproducible Example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . that will help to determine if your compiler installation is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the chain of files included:

```
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/string:56,
             from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
             from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/locale:39,
             from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/fmt/locale.h:11,
             from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.2.0/clocale:42,
```

see there is a `/fmt/locale.h` in there. That is clearly incorrect as the standard library header `<clocale>` should not be including anything from outside the standard library header directory.

This problem arises because you have incorrectly specified `/mingw64/include/fmt` as an include path, so the file `fmt/locale.h` is now found by a `#include "locale.h"` when it should not be.

Your build command should not have any `-I` switches with argument starting `/mingw64` . The `/mingw64/include` directory is enabled on the search path by default .

To use the header whose location is `/mingw64/include/fmt/format.h`,  you write `#include <fmt/format.h>` in your program , and it is found because `/mingw64/include` is searched for that name.